# TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/

Tags: django, templates

I have tried my best to source and to fix this problem, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Currently going through the tangowithdjango tutorial, I'm currently on 5. Templates and Static Media.
http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/templates_static.html

Trying to get my site to show its first template, but just before I reach 5.2 I tried loading my site and got this error message:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /rango/
rango/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/
Django Version: 1.8
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:rango/index.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib
/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 46
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.9
```

Here is my settings.py file:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
# Template from tangowithdjango 5.1: Templates and Static Media
#

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
TEMPLATE_PATH,
)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):

# Construct a dictionary to pass to the template engine as its context.
# Note the key boldmessage is the same as {{ boldmessage }} in the template!
context_dict = {'boldmessage': "I am bold font from the context"}

# Return a rendered response to send to the client.
# We make use of the shortcut function to make our lives easier.
# Note that the first parameter is the template we wish to use.

return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

Sorry about the comments, after a few tries I copied the site's code, but still to no success.

My file structure is as follows:

- workspace
- - tango_with_django_project
- - - manage.py
- - - tango_with_django_project
- - - - settings.py
- - - templates
- - - - rango
- - - - - index.html

To add, here is what is shown at 127.0.0.1:8000/rango :

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/rango/index.html (File does not exist)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/rango/index.html (File does not exist)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` is [deprecated in django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs). You should use the [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#templates) setting instead.  Chances are that you already have the `TEMPLATES` variable in the `settings.py` so alter the [`DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#dirs) key like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH], # <-- HERE --
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Add this below BASE_DIR:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.pardir)
```

Next following should look like this:

```
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'tango_with_django_project/static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =(

  STATIC_PATH,
)

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'tango_with_django_project/templates')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     TEMPLATE_PATH,
 )

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'tango_with_django_project/media')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure is wrong.  check out what this code is doing...

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

according to your directory structure this code returns...

**/root_path/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project**

therefore according to your structure, templates folder is not inside the folder tango_with_django_project which is where it thinks it should be.

you could just specify a direct path to your templates if you want.

```
TEMPLATE_PATH = '/root_project/tango_with_django_project/templates/'
```

On a side note, Tango with Django is the worst name for a tutorial series, possibly ever.